# Excel - .xlsm opens in Protected View, but crashes in regular view upon opening

Tags: excel, protected-mode, xlsm, vba

I have an Excel file that crashes when I try to open it regularly, but it somehow opens in protected view. It's strange because it was working fine yesterday. Then I restarted my computer, and reopened the sheet, and it crashed upon opening. I can open other files fine.

Then I opened it in protected view, and it didn't crash. But of course, I can't work like that, so I click enable editing, and it crashes again. What am I doing wrong?